# Coхранение SqlCe в файл

Tags: c#, sqlce

пришло столкнуться с этой старой технологией и у меня с ней возникла проблема. Суть заключается в том, что я создал таблицу в sdf-файле, через SQL Server Compact Toolbox ввел начальное заполнение (VS 2015 нативно не поддерживает больше этот формат). Теперь пытаюсь написать методы для работы с таблице и для метода Add возникла проблема. Я программно вставляю строки в базу, открываю ее в ToolBox и вижу вставленные данные, но если я повторяю эксперимент с вставкой строк, то ранее вставленные строки исчезают, остается только начальное заполнение.
Собственно вопрос, где я облажался? (не считая выбора технологии)

```
   public void TestTableAdd(string col2, int Col3)
       {

           DataSet oldData;
           DataRow dr;
           try
           {
               connection.Open();
               FillDataInDataset(out oldData, sdaTestTable);
               //create new row assign value to it.
               var tx = connection.BeginTransaction();
               dr = oldData.Tables[0].NewRow();
               dr["col2"] = col2;
               dr["Col3"] = Col3;
               oldData.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
               var old_tx = sdaTestTable.UpdateCommand.Transaction;
               sdaTestTable.UpdateCommand.Transaction = tx;
               var b = sdaTestTable.Update(oldData);
               tx.Commit();
               tx.Dispose();
               sdaTestTable.UpdateCommand.Transaction = old_tx;
               connection.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Catched!");
           }
       }

       public void TestTableAdd2(string col2, int Col3)
       {

           try
           {
               connection.Open();
               var tx = connection.BeginTransaction();
               SqlCeCommand CMD = connection.CreateCommand();
               CMD.Transaction = tx;
               CMD.CommandText = "INSERT INTO[test] ([col2],[Col3]) VALUES ('not sex', 155)";
               CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
               tx.Commit();
               connection.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Catched!");
           }
       }


Пытался и без транзакции и с, и с автогенерацией команды Insert и без.
```

Comment: Вы БД эту проверяете где? Где она создается? Вы поди включили её в проект и каждый раз копируете в папку `Bin/Debug` ? То есть соё предположение - вот вы скомпилировали вашу программу, студия подменила БД в `Bin/Debug` на новый файл, отменив все ваши изменения. Как проверить? Закройте студию, запускайте ваше приложение напрямую из `Bin/Debug` и смотрите результат.

Comment: ps - SQL Compact вполне себе БД, использую её + EF Code first уже более 5 лет, полет нормальный. Много чего в ней не поддерживается, но для неольшого проекта сгодится.

Comment: а что проверять? файл я просто положил в папку Debug, не копирую.

Comment: Что проверять - наличие данных в бд конечно

Comment: Ты был прав, студия заменяла в папке файл базы при каждой компиляции

Comment: Опыт не пропьешь :) Вы не первый с такой проблемой и даже не десятый.